# Which resistor will reduce 5V 2.5A to 5V 2.3A in a parallel connection? For Chinese router

Tags: voltage, power, current, router

I am working on iot project, and I have a problem.
There's a router mi 4c (Chinese version). It used to start working only from outlet adapter. I tried using powerbank, accumulator (with 12V to 5V regulator). It didn't work with those, only with a wall adapter (5V 1A).

I have a powerbank with 2 ports (2.5A both.) I have a router, ESP8266 and an IP camera on one port, and an Arduino, motors, relays, servos and others on thr other port.

I swear! I tested! I know that a device will only eat enough amps, but it looks like mi router 4c doesn't work like that. When enough devices connected to one port of the powerbank, the router starts working. Now when I connected Arduino and motors separately, it doesn't.

I think maybe in this case there are too much amps for router to boot up.

Now I have to find a way to take ≈0.2A coming from powerbank. I know parallel connected resistors will help, but I don't know which resistor to solder. I thought asking for it online will be a good idea.

- Powerbank output: 5V 2.5A
- IP camera: ~0.5A
- ESP8266: ~0.8A
  Mi router 4c: 1A

I wish I bought other little bit expensive router, brcause of this device my project was paused for 3 months.

Comment: The current rating is the maximum the supply can provide. You do not need (and should not include) an additional resistor.

Comment: There is no resistor that can lower current without lowering voltage.

Comment: The router probably shuts down from too much available current - a very odd thing.  I suggest replacing the router with a different brand which operates normally.

Comment: @rdtsc Devices don't shut down from too much available current, how would a router even know how much was available? Why would it care if it was more than it needed? Some power banks on the other hand do shut down from too little current being drawn, which is probably what's happening here.

Comment: @GodJihyo powerbank doesn't shut down because if it would then IP camera and esp8266 would shut down as well.

Comment: @rdtsc I don't want to spend more money for that if it can be solved with electronics. It doesn't shut down. It turns on. But can't complete initialization and restarts itself and it keeps going

Comment: @Finbarr we can do that by connecting it parallel (not series connection)

Comment: It is working alright when I connect arduino as well. That's why I think lowering current might solve the problem

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Comment: "we can do that by connecting it parallel" - that will increase the current flowing out of the supply. That may cause it to regulate properly as discussed by others or it may reduce the supply voltage slightly, which may help if your router is very fussy about this.

Comment: @Finbarr I think you right. Thank you. This discussion surely pointed a direction for me to move forward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question is saying that your router doesn't draw enough current from the powerbank so the powerbank switches off its output. You wish to add a load in parallel to keep the powerbank on.

I suggest that you use a USB hub and plug in something like a USB LED lamp or USB fan to increase the load on the powerbank. This will be simpler than messing around trying to connect a resistor in parallel.

Comment: Apparently it's a common enough problem that someone came up with this:
https://blog.zakkemble.net/smart-power-bank-keep-alive/

Comment: Thank you. That's good idea. But powerbank doesn't shut down. If it did then IP camera and esp 8266 would shut down as well.

Comment: Router doesn't shut down. It simply can't finish setup and reboots and keeps rebooting. But it does work great when arduino is connected to the circuit. That's why I think it's because of the current

Comment: Thank you for the idea!  I will use fan, I guess

Comment: Thank you so much guys!